# I have question related to hang of rootview

Tags: iphone

I have six views i'm using push and pop mechanism for going and coimng back to 1 or another view
In each view's viewwillappear method my code is remove view from superview.
that's how i reach directly from sixth view to 1 st view through this mechanism
but when i click a home button of device on last screen at that time it loads 1 st view as it is expected but it hNGS IT OUT .
WHY IS IT SO?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it like that. Go look up "popViewControllerAnimated:"

You're probably getting memory leaks or something.